# Laravel whereBetween issue , wrong records returned

Tags: laravel

I have two date variables `$to` and `$from`.

```
$from = '2016-06-01';
$to = '2016-06-20';
```

I am using `whereBetween` to search between the two dates.
If I select for example 1st June to 20th June it only displays records from the 1st to the 19th. How do I include the 20th in that search?

Here is an example of my where clause:

```
 ->whereBetween('CompletedDate', array($fromDate, $toDate))
```

Comment: Can you give us an example exactly what `$fromDate` or `$toDate` would be printed off as strings?

Comment: show here fromdate and todate as string.

Comment: @user3158900 , it has been updated

Comment: @ImtiazPabel, it has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the SQL server reads these dates like so...

```
$from = '2016-06-01 00:00:00';
$to = '2016-06-20 00:00:00';
```

If you want to include the latest date, you need to update these accordingly...

```
$from = '2016-06-01 00:00:00';
$to = '2016-06-20 23:59:59';
```

If you are using a datepicker, the same principle applies.  Your logic would probably look something like the following...

```
$fromDate = new DateTime(strtotime('2016-06-01'));
$toDate = new DateTime(strtotime('2016-06-20'));

... ->whereBetween('CompletedDate', array($fromDate->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), $toDate->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59')));
```

Comment: im using a datepicker

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer anyway for a quick example on how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Carbon

You can work better with dates using Carbon.

I came up with a little snippet for you:

```
<?php
public function index()
{
    $from = Carbon::parse('2016-06-01')->startOfDay();
    $to = Carbon::parse('2016-06-20')->endOfDay();
    $users = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
}
```

- [Carbon Documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Don't forget to import Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```